# hector_slam: how to load a saved map (and perform localization)

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, hector-slam, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I read the tutorial about creating a new map with hector_slam and save it.
My question now is: how to load a saved map and use it for localization? (thus substituting amcl)
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47496/hector_slam:-how-to-load-a-saved-map-(and-perform-localization)/) by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-11-21**:
that is exactly what I was searching for!

**Comment by [quentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24914/quentin/) on 2015-11-08**:
I am also really interested in doing that, but still new in ROS. Is there any update?

**Comment by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) on 2020-06-08**:
Does anyone have any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is currently not supported. I meant to add it add some point (shouldn't be too difficult), but I'm quite stuffed with ToDos, so I probably won't be able to implement that functionality in the foreseeable future.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-11-21**:
thanks for the nice work man! I am amazed on how well it works with my bad odom robot. implementing localization with a loaded map would be perfect. could you point some direction on how you would do it? I might give it a try! thanks

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-11-27**:
As long as one doesn't use multiple map resolution levels it shouldn't be too hard. Essentially, the map would only have to be read via some method at startup and not get updated later. The most annoying (even if not really complicated) thing is probably setting the transforms correctly.

**Comment by [musiqsoulchild](https://answers.ros.org/users/21484/musiqsoulchild/) on 2015-03-17**:
Any progress on this yet? I'm trying to use the odom data from hector slam with a pre-saved map. Then I will use move_base with it.

**Comment by [musiqsoulchild](https://answers.ros.org/users/21484/musiqsoulchild/) on 2015-03-17**:
Just brainstorming and was wondering if I just loaded in a presaved map using map_server and remapped the /map topic created from hector slam to something else. Then I could use the localization from hector slam and use a static map. Any comments on this approach?

**Comment by [jjbecomespheh](https://answers.ros.org/users/55607/jjbecomespheh/) on 2020-06-14**:
Hi, may I check if anyone has implemented this (localization only) on Hector SLAM?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that this is not possible, so you'll just save the map as any other occupancy map and use amcl.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answer. So amcl is the only way to perform localization on a saved map? But in this case I have to use odometry, which is not reliable on our custom robot. Is there any other way to perform localization on a saved map using only laser data?
PS: I think that is a pity that this feature is missing in hector_slam, the mapping results are really good and it would be really interesting to use it a complete navigation demo.

---

Originally posted by [randaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1321/randaz/) with karma: 63 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-05**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher can provide something like odometry based on laser. I am not aware of another localization package than amcl.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-06**:
Please do not use answers for comments or discussion. This is not a forum. Instead please either edit your original post or use the comment functionality.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-11-21**:
@dornhege, I took a look and think [laser_scan_mathcer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher) actually computes odom based on laser measurements only and not on matching scans with a previous built map. maybe laser_scan_matcher + amcl might work.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-21**:
Correct. Odometry is what was missing at his robot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have gotten AMCL to work with the LaserScanMatching node using just a Lidar. I set the fixed frame in LaserScanMatching to odom and the base frame to base_link. In AMCL it uses the intuitive parameter names, odom frame is odom, base frame is base_link. The tf tree then goes map -> odom by amcl, odom -> base_link by laser_scan_matching.

I will try to get this working with hector slam also as the odometry, if anyone has gotten that please let me know how!

---

Originally posted by [tb12](https://answers.ros.org/users/29230/tb12/) with karma: 21 on 2017-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a PR that claims to provide this capability now: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/pull/45

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1